# Can't post yammer message

Tags: javascript, yammer

I am trying to post a message from an html page. I am already logged in in another IE window. So the login is successful. I am getting a failure when I post. Can someone take a quick look at this JS and see what might be the issue? Also, All that comes back from msg is that it is an object. How can I find out the properties of this object so I can help debug this myself.

```
    function post() {
        yam.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (response.authResponse) {
                alert(1);
                yam.request({
                    url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: { "body": "HelloTest" },
                    success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); },
                    error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                    Console.log(msg);
                });
            } else {
                alert(2);
                yam.login(function (response) {
                    if (!response.authResponse) {
                        yam.request({
                            url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: { "body": "HelloTest" },
                            success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); },
                            error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: where is your error message? You can debug with f12 on ie

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your second question might be:

```
JSON.stringify(yourObject)
```

I'm not sure if this part is correct:

```
 error: function (msg) { alert("Post was Unsuccessful..." + msg); }
                    Console.log(msg);
```

You might need comma or even move Console.log(msg)...

Comment: I have now tried posting a message, an activity and tried to get the current user. All of the requests come back access denied. The latest is pretty simple: function getUser() {
            yam.request({
                url: "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/users/current.json",
                method: "GET",
                success: function (msg) { alert("Get was Successful!: " + msg); },
                error: function (msg) { console.dir(msg); }
            })
        }